# Multiple ports server in C

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tcp

I have a server that has 2 ports with a socket for each port, each of them doing different thigs. I made this work with `epoll` but I have a question, can 2 different clients connect to each port and use the functionality offered by them at the same time? For example: client1 connects to port X and wants to read data and client2 connects at the same time and wants to write data at the port Y. Is this possible? Thanks!

```
// create the 2 sockets for each port
// bind(), listen() for each
// tried to do this 'parallelism' using epoll but after someone connects
// to a port that port takes over, the other can't be used
epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
if (epollfd == -1) {
   perror("epoll_create1");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

 ev.events = EPOLLIN;
 ev.data.fd = sd;
 if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sd, &ev) == -1) {
    perror("epoll_ctl: listen_sock");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  ev2.events = EPOLLIN;
  ev2.data.fd = sd2;
  if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sd2, &ev2) == -1) {
    perror("epoll_ctl: listen_sock");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (;;) {
    nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
    if (nfds == -1) {
      perror("epoll_wait");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < nfds; ++n) {
      if (events[n].data.fd == sd2) {
         // handle the clients at PORT2 where I just show data from 
         // database, I'm using processes to handle clients
      }
      else if (events[n].data.fd == sd) {
         // handle the clients at PORT1 where they can update/add/delete 
         // from data base, I'm using processes to handle clients
      }
```

Comment: This is possible by using multiple threads, multiple processes or by processing all requests sequentially without blocking in a single process/thread. Without more details we don't know what solution would fit your needs best or if concurrent access can create any problems, e.g. by reading and writing the same data at the same time. I suggest to [edit] your question and create a [mre].

Comment: What are your worries, why do you think it might not work?

Comment: @Bodo Hmm, I don't know what would be useful to share cause I use 2 sockets that I am binding and listening, putting them in the event array and check if  the file descriptor is from first socket I call the handler, same for 2nd socket. But from your examples after creating the sockets I don't know how to approach this. Like for what you said how do I track the "file descriptors" for each socket to handle them correctly?

Comment: @BalentinValtatescu [Edit] your question and show your (simplified) code instead of describing it. Describe what your server is supposed to do. You can create a thread or process for every connection (probably easier to implement) or use an array or list to keep track of all file descriptors and use e.g. `select` to find out which ones need to be handled (might be more complicated).

Comment: @Bodo Done, initially tried to solve this with `epoll` as I said but after a socket accepts a client first it takes over and can't do any operation on other socket.

Comment: If you `fork` a process for every connection, then what problem do you have with your code? If you want to handle this with `epoll`, you have to add the descriptors you get from `accept` to the epoll interest list and handle these in addition to handling new connections. Of course you might need an array or list of data structures to keep track of the state and data of all connections. On closing a connection you have to remove the file descriptor from the epoll interest list. When handling several connections, you will only do one step of the communication in every cycle, e.g. send one block.

Comment: `if (nfds == -1) {...}` <<-- check for errno == EINTR, and continue here.

Comment: @wildplasser Nothing changed.

Comment: Don't expect us to debug&complete your (incomplete) 2000 line program. The only thing we can do is pick the low hanging fruit.

Comment: Yeah I know, but honestly after you said that I really expected some error )) Anyway I just wanted the big idea how to approach one of methods Bodo said. Never been here to have others debug the program, that's why I didn't add the code in the first place.